# Set shipping method price based on payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, shipping-methods

I have added new shipping method `InPost Kurier` in my Magento 2.2.4 also i have enabled Cash on delivery payment method and visa ...

[image]

I have set default price `15` for that shipping method , but now i need to set it to `20` if user choose cash on delivery method

any help please ?

Comment: Wellcome to our community Mustafa! You can use the cart rules to do that, applying disccount to the other shipping methods, is on possible way.

Comment: Thanks, but discount didn't solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created another shipment method and assigned the new price to it , then i customized view of payment methods with each shipment method